# Creating RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in code

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I developing application for windows-phone,
I want to create table with 2 rows an 2 columns 
I create xaml code for this table

```
<Grid Background="White">   
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions/>      
</Grid>
```

I want to create this Grid in code

```
Grid chat_userpicgrid = new Grid();
newgrid.Children.Add(chat_userpicgrid);
```

But I don't know how to create RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Grid newGrid = new Grid();
newGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
newGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
newGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

To position elements in specific cells:

```
Grid chat_userpicgrid = new Grid();
Grid.SetColumn(chat_userpicgrid, 1);
Grid.SetRow(chat_userpicgrid, 1);
newGrid.Children.Add(chat_userpicgrid);
```

Have a look at [the code at the bottom of this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.aspx)