# how do i get rows and columns dynamically in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, layout, windows-phone-8.1

In my application i need to design the seat  layout arrangement in the form of rows and columns dynamically. Please any one suggest me how to get rows and columns and which view i need to use.

this my xaml code

```
 <Grid x:Name="grid"  Background="White">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" Margin="23,56,268,527">Text</Button>
            </Grid>
```

this is .cs code

```
 for (int j = 0; j < jarray.Count; j++)
                   { 

                            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){width=new GridLength(30)});           

                        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(){ Height = new GridLength(30) });

            }
```

but Iam getting empty page.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is "seat layout arrangement"?

Comment: seat layout arrangemt means ..it is like arrangemnt of seats in bus

Comment: Then you can use Grid Layout. Create a Grid in XAML and define Rowdefinition and ColumnDefinition dynamically in code behind and append to grid.

Comment: If your xaml has Grid with name "grid" then in code behind you can rows and column like this. You can use loop for more number of rows and cols.                                         grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()); grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

Comment: please provide any link for dynamic gridview @nishi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating suggestion here:

you can use Grid Layout. Create a Grid in XAML and define Rowdefinition and ColumnDefinition dynamically in code behind and append to grid. If your xaml has Grid with name "grid" then in code behind you can rows and column like this. You can use loop for more number of rows and cols.

```
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

Below are few links for ref:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/17093c72-cfce-40a2-a296-718b741b50da/how-to-dynamically-create-and-fill-grid-or-grid-view-from-c-not-xaml-becouse-i-am-dynamically?forum=winappswithcsharp

[Creating RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108405/creating-rowdefinitions-and-columndefinitions-in-code)

Comment: I tried but its not working for me. it shows empty page.@nishi

Comment: This is why you don't bother answering awful questions.

Comment: If you havent added any control to grid, you will find blank page only because nothing to show in grid.

Comment: Iam adding button control but it shows empty.@nishi

Comment: Works for me, Thanks!